# Projectiles not moving as they are supposed to

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class supportForce extends MovieClip
    {
        public function supportForce()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keyCheck);
        }
        private function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
        private function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
        private function keyCheck(event:Event)
        {
            if (_keyDownStatus[90])
            {
                var GreenLight:Projectile1 = new Projectile1();
                stage.addChild(GreenLight);
                GreenLight.x = Player2Child.x;
                GreenLight.y = Player2Child.y;
            }
        GreenLight.x -= defaultSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

So the projectile here is Projectile1 and it is declared as GreenLight in the keyCheck Function. So in the same function (the ENTER.FRAME function) GreenLight is supposed to move to its left. This does not happen and also an error saying TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at supportForce/keyCheck() appears. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your keyCheck function, GreenLight will be null if _keyDownStatus[90] is false

so put the GreenLight as a class variable

```
    private var lights:Array = [];

    private function keyCheck(event:Event)
    {
        if (_keyDownStatus[90])
        {

             var GreenLight:Projectile1 = new Projectile1();
             stage.addChild(GreenLight);
             GreenLight.x = Player2Child.x;
             GreenLight.y = Player2Child.y;


             for each (var l:Projectile1 in lights)
             {
                 l.x -= defaultSpeed;
             }

              lights.push(GreenLight);
        }
        else
        {
              //remove all Projectile1s in lights from stage and clear lights if you want
        }

    }
```

Comment: It works but I am only able to launch one GreenLight after which nothing appears.

Comment: @Dust do you mean a new Projectile1 will appear on each frame when mousedown?

Comment: sorry to mention it earlier but yes. My bad.

Comment: @Dust so there will be some Projectile1 that keep moving when mouse down?

Answer (score 0):

you create `GreenLight` in if condition scope and if keyCode isnot 90, object of `Projectile1` isnot created and  `GreenLight.x -= defaultSpeed;` there GreenLight is null